# Is it possible to have a widget pop up from the bottom in Flutter ➕ fade in format as the user scrolls?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I would like to implement such an animation in my Flutter app.
I know how to do FAde-in, but I don't know how to implement an animation that pops up from below.
Can someone please give me a hint or two?

https://ahp-web.jp/tsukarenai-ai/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [ModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html)

Usage example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [showModalBottomSheet].

void main() => runApp(const BottomSheetApp());

class BottomSheetApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomSheetApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: const Color(0xff6750a4),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Bottom Sheet Sample')),
        body: const BottomSheetExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomSheetExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomSheetExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't want to stack new Sheets. Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do, can you help me understand your question better?

Comment: It is difficult to tell exactly what it is because we cannot paste video or GIF images on this site.

Comment: You can paste gif's here actually try it!